# iOS 10 - UITableViewController scrolls to the bottom on load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autoscroll, becomefirstresponder

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController` that displays several rows (8 to be exact), where the top row is a custom cell that contains a `UITextField`.  When the view is loaded, I have the keyboard popup immediately by calling `becomeFirstResponder` on that `textfield`.  This all worked fine until I upgraded from **iOS 9** to **iOS 10**.  Now the view jumps to the bottom of the view, with the keyboard covering my last two rows and my `TextField` is off the visible area.  When I comment out the `becomeFirstResponder` call, the jumping goes away, but I lose my keyboard popup of course.  This is what my code looks like...

```
class UserProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  private var userInfoCell: UserInfoTableViewCell?
  ...

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  if indexPath.section == 0 {
    userInfoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userInfoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UserInfoTableViewCell

    if !editMode {
      userInfoCell?.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return userInfoCell!
  }
  else if indexPath.section == 1 {
   ....
```

Then my custom table view cell looks like this...

```
class UserInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate,, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
...

override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  // listen for when user touches a textfield
  nameField.delegate = self
  ...
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

...
```

Things I have tried:

1. Calling `userInfoCell?.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewWillAppear()`
2. Calling `userInfoCell?.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidAppear()`
3. Calling `nameField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `UserInfoTableViewCell.awakeFromNib()`.
4. Calling `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath()` after the call to `userInfoCell?.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()`.
5. removing `super.viewWillAppear()` in my `viewWillAppear()`

None of these have worked for me.

Comment: try this: `let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusa.....` / `return cell`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't do it, unfortunately.  I get the same scroll to the bottom issue.

Comment: Hmmm, did I stump Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

deferring becomeFirstResponder() solved the issue for me

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    userInfoCell?.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()
})
```

Comment: That made it where the screen stays at the top for me as well!  However, now when the screen segues to the table there is a strange flicker of a keyboard, then that goes away then another keyboard comes up.  Maybe because its called in a tableview delegate so is called multiple times???

I've seen this `dispatch_async()` as a solution on many SO posts, but I hesitate to create threads as a general rule.  Is that all that method does - create a thread to wait until the main thread is ready for it?